# Show a fraction of numbers, one above the other, like on Libreoffice

Tags: android, math, textview, formula, fractions

Libreoffice (and other apps like Latex) allows you to use some kind of script language to show really cool mathematical formulas.

I need to use a view (probably a textView) that will be able to shows such formulas, and fractions in particular.

For example "x over y" would look like:

```
x
-
y
```

and so on.

Is there any such solution for this on Android? Maybe a library (with license similar to Apache or better) that allows you to write such things?

Comment: I was going to link to an answer by CommonsWare about using `Html.fromHtml` regarding this and then I noticed you just commented on it.  Guess I don't need to give you the link.  :p

Comment: yes, i know , i wanted to know if it's possible to put it this way (vertically) , and not just x/y (diagonally) .

Answer (score 0):

You could easily extend the view class and replicate this with two TextViews and an ImageView. Probably not the most efficient way of doing this but certainly pretty easy.

Some sudo code but you get the idea..

```
public class FractionView extends View {

  private TextView top;
  private Textview bottom;
  private ImageView line;

  public FractionView(Context context) {
   // instantiate the views
  }

  // TODO add methods to update the text, possibly update positions as well, more stuff?

}
```

Comment: but this requires many views instead of just one , plus i don't want to re-invent the wheel in case such a thing already exists.

Comment: don't get me wrong , it's a nice suggestion that i've thought of too (yet i thought of extending RelativeLayout) , but by using multiple views it could get messy, hard to update , and perform badly. plus it could get really hard to create complex formulas ,like a fraction in a fraction : (x+(y over z) ) over (a+b)

Comment: You said it had to be a view. If do not want to use TextView then the only option left is Canvas which means you have a lot of work ahead of you figuring out the placements and such. Their is a JS library but it would require a WebView: http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html

Comment: i only thought of a textview as an example , of course it would take a lot of work . that's why i've asked if there is a library for it so that i won't have to re-invent the wheel...

Comment: the webView solution seems quite cool . however, is it possible to know what size (width & height) to give to the view ? how would you avoid it being too large to be shown , or too small to be noticed?